# Decoration pattern used for creating JMSMessages / Where should the timeout start

Tags: java, design-patterns, timeout, decorator, messaging

I started to build a messaging framework and I decided to use the decoration pattern for creating JMSMessages.

```
class BaseMessage implements Message { ... }
```

**Abstract decoration**

```
class AbstractDecoration implements Message {
   Message message;

   public AbstractDecoration(Message message) {
      this.message = message
   }
}
```

**Decoration example:**

```
class JsonPayloadDecoration extends AbstractDecoration { ... }
```

**Usage example:**

```
...

IMessage m = new BaseMessage(...);
m = new ExpireDecoration(m, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
m = new TextPayloadDecoration(m, "Text!");
m = new CorrelationDecoration(m, "123456");
m = new PriorityDecoration(m, 9);
m = new NonPersistentDecoration(m);
m = new QueueDestinationDecoration(m, "JMSTEST.DECORATIONTEST1");
m = new ErrorHandlerDecoration(m, errorhandler, 1000);

// requestor handles MessageProducers
// m.send will create the real JMSMessage and use the requestor
// to send the message with a MessageProducer
m.send(requestor);
```

At first I would like to get some input about the whole decoration idea and now to my real question. The `errorhandler` of `ErrorHandlerDecoration` has a timeout. When should the `timeout` start? When it's created or when `m.send` is called? I am arguing with my colleagues about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't a "timeout" triggered when a message takes too long to send? It should probably start when `send` is called, unless the constructor is doing something special other than populating fields.

Regarding your question about the wisdom of using dectorator pattern: decorator pattern is great for offering permutations of features, which seems to be your case (however, this usage is not present in your code sample). If you're only ever going to apply one decorator to the Message, consider using the Strategy Pattern instead.

Also be careful of mutually exclusive decorators. If you have too many of these, it might just be confusing to keep track of which decorators are compatible with which.

**Edit** in response to your comment: One way to ensure incompatible decorators aren't being used together is get the list of decorators applied to the object so far and throw an exception when you see a conflict. To get the list of decorators, maybe add this method to AbstractDecoration:

```
List<AbstractDecoration> getDecorations() {
    List<AbstractDecoration> decorations;
    if (message instanceof AbstractDecoration) {
        decorations = ((AbstractDecoration) message).getDecorations();
    }
    else {
        decorations = new ArrayList<AbstractDecoration>();
    }

    decorations.add(this);
    return decorations;
}
```

So once you have the list of decorators already applied, just simply check instanceof on each one to detect a conflict. Note that you'll have to do this on both ends of the mutually exclusive decorators in question or else this validation won't happen when the decorators are applied in one order versus the other.

Slightly feels like a hack. I'm no pro on Decorator pattern, so I have no idea what the standard is for solving this problem; I came up with this on the spot.

**Edit:** After thinking about this some more, it might make more sense to do this validation in the constructor of AbstractDecoration. Then, your rules are centralized and you can even delegate them to another class.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you know a way for handling mutually exclusive decorators? I do have some decorators which shouldn't be used if another is used.

Comment: I build this `static <T> T getDecoration(Message m, Class<T extends AbstractDecorator> decoration)` for that purpose. It returns the Decoration's instances. Problem is if there are more than one for `decoration`.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty clever I hadn't thought of that. What do you mean by "if there are more than one for `decoration`?" And what's the problem? Can you just call getDecoration(m, T) for each mutually exclusive T and check if they exist?